# Sql Server - Select Into Linked Server

Tags: linked-server, sql-server-2017

I linked an oracle db to my sql server.

I need to create a same table as linked server on my local db.

I'm trying to execute SELECT INTO query but I taking an error.

```
SELECT * INTO ABC_SYSUSERS FROM [OfficeOracle]..[PROJECTA].[SYSUSERS]
```

This is my error message.

> The OLE DB provider "ORAOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "OfficeOracle"
>   supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "USERNAME"
>   (compile-time ordinal 1) of object ""PROJECTA"."SYSUSERS"" was
>   reported to have a "DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISFIXEDLENGTH" of 16 at compile time
>   and 0 at run time.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I could not fix the error which I mention above but I fixed my problem with using OPENQUERY;

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServerName, 'SELECT * FROM DBName.Schema.Table')
```